# 2.4" TFT LCD is only showing white screen, but the touch functions still work

Tags: lcd, tft

Hi (Sorry for the long post).
The other day I finally found a code that worked on my standard 2.8" TFT LCD by Simkeim, but then I pressed the bottom left corner too hard and the screen went white. The code is a calculator code and it worked because the screen showed the numbers and the screen saver, but when I pressed the screen nothing happened. After the screen went white, I "opened" it and saw no damage to the screen. I have tried a bunch of example sketches and now the touch functions work, but nothing is displayed on the screen. The LCD does not have any wires, it just plugs in the board. When I upload a sketch, the backlight changes brightness a bit, and there is a slight line on the left side of the screen, when the code uses dark colors, I can press two parts of the screen and the screen goes dark (except for a small part of the left side).

Could the screen be damaged by pressure?

This is what the LCD looks like:

[image: LCD Screen Module]

[image]

Comment: It's dead, Jim.

Comment: what do you mean by `opened it`?

Comment: I just took the top part of the LCD off to see the screen, and it had no damage.

Comment: ```but then I pressed the bottom left corner too hard and the screen went white.``` Meh. It should be quite obvious what happened to it.